# Xamarin.Forms Android Applications start 2 processes after use share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.forms, intentfilter

Currently, I app developing an application which uses share intent. but when I share a file to my app, my application starts another process.

Steps to reproduce.

1. start the application.
2. go to gallery/file manager.
3. select a file and share to the current application.
4. Show list applications are running.

Result:
My application starts in two different processes (Please see the screenshot)

[image: image 1]

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Could  you try switching between these two applications and see if they work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It needs android:launchMode="singleTask/singleInstance" in the activity.